# How to download Google Drawings files 'raw' from Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive, google-drawings

When creating a file in Google Drawings, the file is saved in Google Drive. As "backup", I would like to download a drawing from Google Drive in a format that I can later upload again and open and edit in Google Drawings. Whenever I right-click the file and then choose `Download` in Google Drive, the file is converted to a `.jpg` and so is not editable anymore (also pixelated). This is even done if I select the file together with another file (a Google Docs file, for example). In this case a `.zip` is produced, but the Google Drawings file again comes out as a `.jpg`.

From within Google Drawings there is only the option to export the file to `.pdf`, `.svg`..., but not to download it in a file format that Google Drawings understands (I found online that the file ending might be `.gdraw`, but forcing that didn't help either).

Answer (score 1):

Google didn't published what file format they use for Google Document Editors files, including Google Drawings.

By the other hand, the file extensions used by Google Drive backup and sync and File Stream installable apps aren't real file versions of the related document, they only have the document URL, in a similar that .lnk files have the file path.

I think that the best that we could to is to analyze the web browser cache / application local storage to figured out how the required data is handled by the web browser but I'm not sure if that is allowed by the Google terms and conditions.

Comment: It seems Google Drawings is part of Google Docs (same URL base name). As such, I think the drawings at least don't count towards your quota/storage capacity, so one could leave them 'online only'. But still a bit sad that it's not easy to just download an editable format.

Answer (score 0):

The file extension is: .gdraw

If you have a Chromebook you can sign in using the account you want to transfer it from and since it has a file explorer you can get file extensions (usually automatically enabled) and you can find the file and then import it to something like mediafire.com or mega.nz or any other file cloud besides your Google Drive for that account you getting the file from.

If you can transfer your Chromebook to your phone as I can (There is always a way but not always with Apple products | for that you will need something like turbo client FTP and ? file transfer service you can that working \with installing the Chrome extension and app) but I would highly recommend that you use a cloud or private cloud (or a nas | AKA A Network Attached Storage That is Private AND MUST BE TOKEN CARE OF PROPERLY AND IS MORE THAN LIKELY HOOKED UP TO YOUR INTERNET WITH A RJ45 ETHERNET CABLE) and you can sign out but pressing the power key usually above backspace on the keyboard.

to import it into the new account you will have to sign in to that account and import it to Google Drive open it click open with and click Google Drawings. it should create that file into a new file for Google Drawing Application but don't delete it because it could take a little time for Google to get the drawing right on the loading screen. In other words, it might have issues with images and sometimes background transferring. But it should work considering I have done this trick before quite a lot of times.